# Trying to capture a video on Android with timestamps

Tags: android, opencv, video

I'm trying to implement an Android app that records a video, while also writing a file containing the times at which each frame was taken. I tried using MediaRecorder, got to a point where I can get the video saved, but I couldn't find a way to get the timestamps. I tried doing something like:

```
while (previous video file length != current video file length)
    write current time to text file;
```

but this did not seem to work, as file length doesn't seem to be updated frequently enough (or am I wrong?).

I then tried using OpenCV and managed to capture the images frame by frame (and therefore getting timestamps was easy), but I couldn't find a way to join all the frames to one video. I saw answers referring to using NDK and FFmpeg, but I feel like there should be an easier solution (perhaps similar to the one I tried at the top?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) to capture the video, but that gets complicated quickly, especially if you want audio as well.  You can recover timestamps from a video file by walking through it with [MediaExtractor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html).  Just call `getSampleTime()` on each frame to get the presentation time in microseconds.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but I just needed the same thing. With the camera2 api you could stream to multiple targets. So you can stream from one and the same physical camera to the MediaRecorder and at the same time to an ImageReader. The ImageReader has the [ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener), the "onImageAvailable" callback you can use for querying the frames for their timestamps:

```
image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
long cameraTime = image.getTimestamp();
```

Not sure whether streaming to mulitple targets requires certain hardware capabilities, though (such as multiple image processors). I guess, modern devices have like 2-3 of them.

EDIT: [This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.html#createCaptureSession(android.hardware.camera2.params.SessionConfiguration)) looks like every camera2 capable device can stream to up to 3 targets.

EDIT: Apparently, you can use an [ImageReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader) for capturing the individual frames and their timestamps, and then use an [ImageWriter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageWriter) to provide those images to downstream consumers such as a [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec), which records the video for you.

Comment: Hey! Passing Images from `ImageReader` -> `ImageWriter` -> `MediaCodec` sounds like amazing magic, but doesn't always work. ImageReaders are CPU by default, and the MediaCodec can't really handle the Image you pass to it (tried with .PRIVATE, .YUV_420_888 and .RGBA_8888 formats). So this approach does not work. Honestly, I am running out of ideas if it is even possible to get CPU access before encoding to a video on Android. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on fadden's answer, the easiest way to go is to record using [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) (the [Camera2 example](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java) helped me a lot) and *after* that extracting timestamps via [MediaExtractor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html). I want to add a working MediaExtractor code sample:

```
MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
extractor.setDataSource(pathToVideo);
do {
    long sampleMillis = extractor.getSampleTime() / 1000;
    // do something with sampleMillis
}
while (extractor.advance() && extractor.getSampleTime() != -1);
```